# What does frequency variable, specifically in r seastests package, refer to?

Tags: r, time-series, data-science, forecasting

I am using the R package seastests and specifically using the function isSeasonal however I am unsure what the frequency variable refers to. Additionally if the frequency variable refers to the number of periods in a year, what happens when I pass in subdaily data? Should I transform this into having a daily unit?
**P.S. I am new to posting software questions online, if there a better place to post this please let me know**

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seastests/versions/0.14.2/topics/isSeasonal
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seastests/seastests.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The frequency parameter refers to the number of observations per periodic cycle for which you want to test.
So if you have a monthly time series, frequency=12.
For a daily time series we would have frewuency=365 for the annual cycle (currently the seastest package cannot deal with non-integer time series, but this will change in an upcoming release later this year) or frequency=7 for the weekday pattern.